# IBM AIX collect real-time network statistics programmatically without indefinite polling

Tags: performance, unix, aix, netstat

I need to collect network statistics in IBM AIX in real-time programmatically. Specifically the number of bytes transmitted (TX) and received (RX)

Searched the web and found few ways which are all using the shell commands like `netstat`, `entstat`, `topas` so on. Also found `Perfstat API programming` which provided API to get the network interface statistics programmatically.

My requirement is to write to a file with date, time and number of bytes transmitter, whenever data is transmitted, for this I have to run the `Perfstat API` in infinite loop. This leads to heavy utilization of the CPU cycle.

I would like to know if there is any way to set a trigger so that only when some data is transmitted I will invoke the `Perfstat API` and update the stat in the file?

Comment: You say "API" but I want to make sure of what you're trying to do.  Can you explain your requirements?  Are you looking to trigger an event whenever data transfers?  Is this something you're periodically going to query to see how much data has gone by?  How "real time" does it need to be?

Comment: yes it may be a event trigger or any function call like select() which can tell about send or recv events

Comment: You still haven't described your use case. It makes a difference when it comes to how to approach it.

Comment: have made changes to make the description clear